# Need help to convert to multiclass hierarchy

Tags: c#

Coding a bot for Discord and wanting to make it easier to debug if error.

I want to take this

```
private static void Main(string[]) args)
{
    var client = new DiscordClient();
    client.Connect(" ");
    var commands = new client.Services.Get<CommandService>();
    commands.CreateCommand("test")
        .Description("This is a test command.")
        .Do(async e =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("Test Successful!");
            });
}
```

and, if possible, make it so each command has its own class file so it's something like this

```
namespace Console.scripts
{
    class test
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("test")
            .Description("This is a test command.)
            .Do(async e =>
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendMessage("Test Successful!");
                });
    }
}
```

I've never been good with multiclasses, even an example of something similar would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an interface `IDiscordCommand` with a name, description and a method that runs the command.

```
public interface IDiscordCommand
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    void Run(CommandEventArgs e);
}
```

A sample implementation would be

```
public class TestCommand : IDiscordCommand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public void Run(CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Channel.SendMessage("Test");
    }
}
```

Then on your program you can create a list with all commands available, and foreach command register it with the `CommandService` like this

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new DiscordClient();
        client.Connect(" ");

        RegisterCommands(client.Services.Get<CommandService>());
    }

    public static void RegisterCommands(CommandService commandService)
    {
        var commands = new List<IDiscordCommand>();
        commands.Add(new TestCommand());

        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            commandService.CreateCommand(command.Name)
                .Description(command.Description)
                .Do(command.Run);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from my understanding currently I'd use the CommandEventArgs event but I've run into a problem on line ".Do(command.Run);"
"This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously"
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement". Note edited the line to ".Do(async e => command.Run);"

Comment: Then on the command class (in this case `TestCommand`) add `async` to the `Run` method signature. Then change to `.Do(async e => await command.Run(e));`.

Comment: Async comes up as an unknown method when applied outside of the SDK.

Comment: You have to change `public void Run(CommandEventArgs e)` to `public async void Run(CommandEventArgs e)`

Comment: "Cannot await 'void'"

Comment: Oops! Since now it is async you also have to change the return type to `Task`, so it should be `public async Task Run(CommandEventArgs e)` (you also have to change on the interface)

Comment: It works except for loading of name and description. Command injection works otherwise and I thank you greatly for your time and patience.